# How to read recordset as string in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, recordset

I have some code to read records from a database. when i read , the recordset variable modifies the table value to its own format.
For Eg:

In Database

> Time value is 12345 (Not date & time) but when record set reads it, it
>   comes as   For Eg: 23-06-2012
>   10:15:23

I just found that the recordset itself stores values in its own format after doing.

`Set rs = CmdSqlData.Execute()`

So is there any way to define a recordset as `String`?

Here is the code.

```
Dim rs As ADODB.RecordSet
Set rs = CmdSqlData.Execute()
Do While (rs.EOF = FALSE And rs.BOF = FALSE)
  p = rs.GetRows(1)
  cell(1,1) = p(0,0)
Loop
```

Can anyone please let me know how to read the data as String (as it is in database) so that no change in format will occur.

Note: I can not convert Excel cell format due to other requirements but I want to read everthing as String From Table

Comment: Try adding this one line before `cell(1,1)=p(0,0)` .. `cell(1,1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout : i wont have this format as result always as i too have other columns. I may not know when this format is coming to cell. I have already made the excel to String format for all Cells due to some requirement. I just want to read record set as "String".
Is there any other way

Comment: I believe there is a `rs.GetString()` Method.

Comment: Found it... See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676975%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @SiddharthRout : GetRows() will fetch all columns in a row. Similarly will GetString() fetch for all column values ?

Comment: Yes, GetString returns all columns of all or a specified number of rows

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I have seen that already. Anyhow let me try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @SiddarthRout : GetString() simply stores all values of a Row in single shot. I wanted to split like array ?I can not do p(0,0) or p(0,1)...

Comment: @SiddharthRout Just Fount that recordset itself stores values in its own format after doing Set rs = CmdSqlData.Execute() ; So is there any way to define record set as String ??

Comment: If you have a code sample, please cut and paste it into the editor. Don't retype it as that may introduce errors which will be very hard to spot.

Comment: @JP. I am working on server machine. So can not.

Answer (score 5):

If you write

```
CStr(p(0,0))
```

To a cell, Excel will convert to the appropriate type for the content, so if p(0,0) is a number, the cell will be numeric.

However, if you write

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "'" & p(0, 0)
```

Cell A1 will contain '2 to view, but can be manipulated as a string. This is left over from the early days of Excel, where to enter a string you had to prefix it with a single quote.

```
A1
2   
=A1=2   FALSE
=A1="2" TRUE
```

Comment: + 1 I almost forgot about `'` LOL

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Will that single quote be ignored and only string will be stored in excel ? (Sorry i am working on server machine so i cant check immediately)

Comment: @logan What do you mean? What part of my explanation is not clear (the answer is mine, btw)?

Comment: @Remou : ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "'" & p(0, 0) 
in above , will the single quote be ignored while storing.

Comment: If you output the file to .txt, the single comma will not be included, if you refer to the column in ADO, refer to it as text, the single comma will not be relevant.

Comment: However, if you click in the cell and look at the address bar, you will see '2

Comment: @Remou : Still i have doubt. return value for p(0,0)='22/02/2012 10:10:15' But actually in database its only 10:10:15
How will the above statement change p(0,0) to '10:10:15'
I want the values (p(0,0)) to be read as string.

Comment: In Database the time value is stored as number but excel/VBA reads it as a Date field. I want the number to read as string so that no conversion happens

Comment: In my tests, a time from a database stored either as a string or as a time was copied to Excel as a string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12907/discussion-between-remou-and-logan)

Comment: Sorry i can not chat & prohibited in office. Please tell me here itself

Comment: It is frowned upon by Stackoverflow. You have changed the question.

Comment: In my tests, a time from a database stored either as a string or as a time was copied to Excel as a string.
What do you want Excel to show? 1234 or 22:02? Note that if you have previously copied a date to a cell, the next time you enter a value from your DB it will be stored as a date.
Selecting a time and a text from my table:
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1) = "'" & p(0, 0) 
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1) = "'" & p(1, 0) 
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 1) = p(0, 0) 
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 1) = p(1, 0)
Returns
21:00:00 
21:00:00 
0.875 
0.875

Comment: I just want to show as it is in Database. 
In this case, i want to show 1234.
Sorry if i confused.
My question is very simple. I just want to read everything(every cols, rows) as string

Comment: @Remou Just Fount that recordset itself stores values in its own format after doing Set rs = CmdSqlData.Execute() ; So is there any way to define record set as String ??

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Remou Teradata --> Recordset sets its datatype to timestamp based on tables datatype. Is there any way to set the recordset as String ?