# Define a VBA Recordset as String

Tags: vba, excel, recordset, teradata

When we define a record set in VBA & read the data from database, recordset converts its datatype to Table's column data type.

```
Dim rs as adobb.RecordSet 
Set rs = CmdSqlData.Execute() ' After this rs fields will be stored based on table's datatype
```

Is there any way to set the recordset itself to String and Perform,

```
Set rs = CmdSqlData.Execute()
```

For Eg: if there is a timestamp value(which has integer value) in Database table definition,  Recordsset sets its field datatype to timestamp.

The problem is , In database,

> Time value is 12345 (Not date & time) but when record set reads it, it
>   comes as   For Eg: 23-06-2012
>   10:15:23

I wanted the value as 12345

Comment: Why not answer my question, which database? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153073/how-to-read-recordset-as-string-in-vba/11153860#11153860

Comment: @Remou :  I answered !. Its Teradata

Comment: You will need to adjust the sql of your recordset in keeping with the database you are using.

Comment: @Remou : Its not taking it from SQL, it is taking it from Tables Definition. Because, how can be the value 12345 be considered as Timestamp in VBA ?

Comment: All times and dates in MS Office are numbers. Type in a number into a cell then format it as a date.

Comment: The problem is i can not do string conversion in Query itself because i may not know which column is date or string. Is there any method to select sql as string for all columns ?

Comment: OR is there any other method otherthan Recordset for retrieving data from SQL databases

Comment: Why don't you just convert the recordset value back to its numeric representation?  You say you can't do the conversion in your SQL, so that's your only remaining option.  If you really need numbers in your recordset and not Dates, then do an initial select with a clause which will return no records (eg "select * from tablename where 1=2"): you can look at the names and the types of the fields returned and create a select statement which includes the required cast() conversions for any Date columns.

Comment: its a complex process And there are numerous data type is available . . For eg time(6) format And user specified formats . . Looking for simple process for reading the data as in database . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to convert this timestamp alone for now. But There are number of timestamp format available. I can not automate the SQL query to convert from different datatype to string.
I require VBA to read the TERADATA VALUE as string
What i did ,

```
    If Field_format = "99:99:99" then
    Sql = "Select Cast(Field_format as integer) from Mytable"
    Elseif Field_format = "99:99:99.999" then
    Sql = "Select Cast(Field_format as Float) from Mytable"
    Elseif Field_format = "99:99:99.999" then
    Sql = "Select Field_format from Mytable"
    End if
...
Set rs = CmdSqlData.Execute()
```

Kindly note there are so many datatypes available in teradata (Around 400+) , i can not convert everthying as above.

> I just wanted to VBA to read Teradata values as string.
>   **Wondering There is no VBA Expert in StackOverflow**

Answer (score 2):

Your SELECT statement will need to perform an explicit CAST for the Teradata TIMESTAMP to FLOAT (DATE is INTEGER)

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
     , CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS FLOAT) AS NumericTimeStamp
;
```

The rest of the VBA you should be able to work out as the Recordset will recognized the NumericTimeStamp as a FLOAT and not a TIMESTAMP.

**Edit**

The following SELECT statement will take an integer with a FORMAT clause and return a character data type as a result of the double cast:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(1234 as INTEGER FORMAT '99:99:99') AS CHAR(8));
```

Have you tried to open your recordset with a SELECT statement that you explicitly CAST the column containing the time as a CHAR(8)?

Comment: The problem is , In database, Time value is 12345 (Not date & time) but when record set reads it, it comes as <Todays Date DD/MM/YYYY> <time HH:MM:SS> For Eg: 23-06-2012 10:15:23

Comment: Two questions: What is the data type on the table definition and what is the FORMAT clause on the table definition?

Comment: Field as Integer Format 99:99:99
I managed to convert this timestamp alone. There are number of timestamp format available. I can not automate the SQL query to convert from different datatype to string.
I require VBA to read the TERADATA VALUE as string

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to a SQL Server database, the timestamp datatype is a binary field used to determine if the record has changed or not (see [How to convert SQL Server's timestamp column to datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)) . This is different than an datetime field which holds, as it says, times and dates.

Returning a string from a recordset in ADO would like something like:

```
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL as string
Dim strSomething as string

strSQL = "SELECT fld1 FROM tbl1"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connetion
cn.ConnectionString = {your connection string here}
cn.open
rs.open strSQL, cn
While Not rs.EOF
    strSomething = rs!fld1
Wend
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Comment: what if the fld1 is a time stamp numeric value in database ? Will the strsomething be having same numbers ? What my problem is while reading itself record sets converting in to date And time value . .

Comment: By declaring the strSomething as a string, VBA should handle it exactly as it comes out of the recordset. If it's still coming out as a date, and you need to convert it to some number, try something like CDbl(# your date #)/

Comment: this is not worked. As i already said,In Database value is number(as timestamp) but rs!fld1 is a timestamp value. you can not put it into string.